# PCIe riser 1X-16X on a 16X socket from Motherboard - No input

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, cryptomining

I have a motherboard with a single 16X PCIe and two 1X PCIe sockets. To use with 3 gpu's. [Motherboard Manual](http://download1.gigabyte.eu/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_8i915pl-g_2x_e.pdf)

Im using 1X to 16X risers to use my gpus. On both 1X sockets risers with gpus work perfect and input is showing on the monitor.

But whenever I user the riser on the 16X PCIe socket from the motherboard, I am getting no input from any of the gpus.

Why is this happening?

To clarify:

- All risers work fine, I tested them individualy.
- All gpus work fine
- 16X PCIe socket works fine using without a riser too.

As I know (and read on forums) its supposed to work using a 1X-16X riser on a 16X socket right? This is for mining purposes, so I dont mind about 1X nor 16X advantage/disadvantages.

Edit: I tried to plug a gpu directly to the 16x motherboard and a second gpu with a riser to the 1x and windows boots normaly and they both appear on windows. So does that mean with a 16x-16x ribbon riser this will still work? I mean, the problem is that I cant use a 1x-16x riser on a 16x motherboard slot in my case? Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly dependent on the motherboard in question and extremely situational, different motherboards react differently to different versions of risers in different slots.

Also older motherboards sometimes share the lanes between 16x and 1x slots disabling the 1x slots when 16x is used (this should be noted in the manual).

Also yea, 1x cards/risers have no theoretical problems working in a 16x slot but sometimes the reality is different..

I suggest trying a ribbon style riser with this motherboard in the 16x slot, the usb ones while convenient often follow the pcie spec in a very minimalist fashion which your motherboard probably has a problem with. Ribbon risers don't change the signalling in any way so they have a better success rate.

Comment: The exact motherboard [manual is this](http://download1.gigabyte.eu/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_8i915pl-g_2x_e.pdf). I can`t find anything related to sharing lanes between 16x and 1x slots. Could you tell me where should that be mentioned? I'll try with a ribbon riser if so.

Comment: It quite probably isn't mentioned. The BIOS is probably the issue... being picky and expecting a card that identifies as x16, that is in an x16 slot to have all 16 lanes available. Use a 16-lane riser and report back.

Comment: @Flowen In the few instances where I've seen it, its usually an asterisk with a footnote around the table that mentions all the expansion options (pcie, sata, usb, etc). If you can't find it then its probably not the case.

Comment: @Attie I tried to plug a gpu directly to the 16x motherboard and a second gpu with a riser to the 1x and windows boots normaly and they both appear on windows. So does that mean with a 16x-16x ribbon riser this will still work? I mean, the problem is that I cant use a 1x-16x riser on a 16x motherboard slot in my case? Does that make any sense?

Comment: That should be the case, yes.

Comment: @user81993 Ribbon riser worked!